# Techniques used with Entity Framework navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

Starting to explore EF4.3.

Using navigation properties makes things very easy, although I have a concern in one area, where I'd appreciate some advice on how other people deal with this scenario.

Take the scenario - Store.Programme.ProgrammeAccountNumber when lazy loading nested properties.

Store is the entity I'm querying.

Programme is an entity, and also a navigation property of Store, and ProgrammeAccountNumber is a property of Programme.

To get the original entity, I write something like this:

```
  public static IQueryable<Store> FindActive()
    {
        var r = new ReadRepo<Store>(Local.Items.Uow.Context);

        return r.Find(s => s.StoreStatusId == (int)StoreStatus.Active);
    }
```

But lets suppose that Programme has it's own status fields:

```
var store = StoreBL.FindActive()
    .Where(s => s.Programme != null && s.Programme.ProgramStatusId = (int)ProgrammeStatus);
```

It's not easy to remember all the conditions for each entity each time the query extends beyond the original entity.

Imagine a chain of properties where I have a product, that has a start/end dates and a status, that belongs to a store, that has a programme with a status and is valid if the category it operates is live.

I got to thinking there must be a technique for dealing with this effectively, or is it a case of using Lazy Loading sparingly?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Whta happens when you have more than one store that is active?

Comment: In the example above, I will have more than one store active. My concern is when navigating there are no safeguards unless I remember that Programme has a status too.

Comment: My single advice is to disable LazyLoading. Always.

Comment: @JYL Thats an option but it seems such a waste.

Comment: @user1437135 : not really. Thanks to lazy evaluation of Linq and the "Include()" method, it is quite efficient to work without LazyLoading. You just have to know which data you will need prior to execute the query.

Comment: @JYL - its doesn't help that i'm running a fairly normalise db. Offer table can be link to 1 of 4 tables depending on the order type. When I grab 'offers', it includes mixed types so I'll still need to check individually when I'm databinding :(